# cached_network_image throw Invalid image data exception if url is 404

Tags: flutter

I am using CachedNetworkImage in book list. If image url is wrong or 404, it is throw Invalid image data exception in firebase Crashlytics report. But in app, image in list is showing black container that in written in errorWidget. My question is how I can catch this error instead of throwing exception. You can even get the exception at debug mode.

Now firebase is keeping on sending the email alert, because of repetitive crashes.

```
CachedNetworkImage(
              width: 110.0,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              imageUrl: ebook.thumbnail,
              placeholder: (context, url) => Container(color: Colors.black12),
              errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                  Container(color: Colors.black12),
            )
```

Comment: It seems it is currently impossible to completely catch: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/336#issuecomment-760769361 and https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/536#issuecomment-760857495